# For what values of u is this a valid autocorrelation function

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Suppose I have an auto-correlation function $R_Y$ of a random process $Y$ which is

$$R_Y[t]=3 \delta[t] - 2(\delta[t+1] + \delta[t-1]) + u$$

where the $R_Y[\tau]=E[Y[t]Y[t+\tau]]$ and using the the Wiener–Khintchine theorem to get the power spectral density (PSD),

$$R_Y(t)  \xrightarrow{\mathscr{F}} S_Y(f)$$

**My question is for what values of $u$ is $R_Y$a valid autocorrelation function?**

Looking at the Fourier transform of $R_Y$,

$$S_Y[f] = 3 - 4 \cos(2\pi f) + u \delta(f)$$

I believe there is no value of $u$ which makes this autocorrelation valid since any $u$ will result in $S_Y$ having negative values.

Is this correct?

Comment: What is the relevance of the Fourier transform taking negative values?

Comment: @Math1000 The power spectral density of R_Y must have non negative values everywhere for it to be a valid random process.

Comment: If $\delta(f)=1$, then $u\delta(f)=u$, and so..?

Comment: @Math1000 Only equals u when f=0